# How to restrict year input field to 4 digit in angular material

Tags: html, angular, angular-material

Here is my HTML code snippet
I am using material design
I want to restrict user to don't enter more digit then the mat-date picker

```
<td width="1%" class="inputlabel" nowrap="">Start Date</td>
    <td width="30%">
    <!-- <input type="date" [(ngModel)]="startDate" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}">
     -->
    <mat-form-field appearance="fill" maxlenght='4'>
    <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}"
    [(ngModel)]="startDate">
    <mat-datepicker-toggle class="calender-date-picker" matSuffix [for]="picker">
     </mat-datepicker-toggle>
     <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
      </mat-form-field>
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" tabindex="-1"><img
     [matTooltip]="get_Tooltip('search_creationDateRange')" matTooltipPosition="right"
    src="assets/images/info.gif" border="0" align="middle"></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

try to slice the startDate string to 10 characters on key Press.

```js
<input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}"
    [(ngModel)]="startDate" (keyup)="sliceDate()">
    
    
sliceDate(){
this.startDate = this.startDate.slice(0,10)
}
```